# HDR mode disabled on Sony A55

Tags: sony, hdr, sony-alpha

So I recently came into possession of a used Sony Alpha55 DSLT with the stock 18-70 lens, which was actually an upgrade from my old unit. Anyways, I'm more than satisfied with it, apart from one thing: the "Auto HDR" setting in the function menu is greyed out and disabled, apparently regardless of what the rest of my settings are. I've tried it on Program, both shutter and aperture priority modes, and full-manual, with no luck.

Am I missing something here? Is it only available under certain exposure settings? Or do I need to update my firmware or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it with image settings set to JPEG instead of RAW? The *Auto HDR* function is not selectable if you are saving raw images.

There are also other settings that will disable *Auto HDR*. They're listed on pages 108-9 of the [α33/α55 Instruction Manual](https://docs.sony.com/release/slta33.pdf):
[image]

Comment: A less helpful answerer (e.g. me) might even have just asked, "Did you check the manual?"